# Migrating jest to vitest and issues with tanstack react-query

Tags: react-query, vitest, tanstackreact-query

We recently migrated from Jest to Vitest and realized that React Query doesn't behave the same way on Vitest. When we use the useQuery hook, it's triggered initially, and the loading state is set to true. However, even if the query function successfully fetches the results, the useQuery hook doesn't update the loading state. The only workaround I've managed to find is to run all timers, and then I see the useQuery hook updating the state correctly.

Has anyone else experienced a similar issue before this?